# Building App in intel xdk for Apple(IOS)

Tags: ios, intel-xdk

The screen is scroll-able with my header and footer fixed, but i am not liking that. How can i remove the scroll? 
Please if anyone can help me out .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uquml.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the `intelxdk.config.additions.xml` file:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```